# C Programming Issues: Passing, creating, and returning structures in functions.

Tags: c, function, pointers, structure

This function doesn't work and I can't figure out why. It compiles fine and the program seems to run, however upon close examination and debugging I'm discovering that:

```
newImg->x = b;
newImg->y = a;
```

Isn't actually working and it's causing problems. I tried copying with newImg=img but that doesn't let me change the values of newImg later. They remain the exact same. I also tried modifying the values of img, then doing newImg, but debugging shows that newImg is getting extreme values.

Here is the structure:

```
typedef struct
{
     unsigned char grayscale;
} PGMPixel;

typedef struct
{
     int x, y;
     PGMPixel *data;
} PGMImage;
```

Here is the function:

```
static PGMImage *rotatePGM(PGMImage *img)
{   
    PGMImage *newImg;


    // Memory allocation for pgm
    newImg = (PGMImage *)malloc(sizeof(PGMImage));
    if (!newImg) 
    {
         fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory\n");
         exit(1);
    }

    //memory allocation for pixel data
    newImg->data = (PGMPixel*)malloc(newImg->x * newImg->y * sizeof(PGMPixel));
    if (!newImg) 
    {
         fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory\n");
         exit(1);
    }

    int a = img->x;
    int b = img->y;
    newImg->x = b;
    newImg->y = a;  

    int u = a - 1;
    int v = b - 1;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    if(newImg)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < b; j++)
            {
                img->data[(j*a)+(u-i)].grayscale = img->data[(i*b)+j].grayscale;
            }
        }
    }   
    return newImg;
}
```

I'm using MinGW GCC and windows 8 if that helps.

Comment: Have you initialised `img->x` and `img->y`?  What are the values you're seeing assigned to `newImg`?

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc` in a C program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
newImg->data = (PGMPixel*)malloc(newImg->x * newImg->y * sizeof(PGMPixel));
```

is wrong - it uses `newImg->x` and `newImg->y` before they are initialised.  You should presumably use the values from `img` instead

```
newImg->data = malloc(img->x * img->y * sizeof(PGMPixel));
```

I've made another small change to that line - [you don't need to cast the return from malloc](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html)

You also use the wrong `PGMPixel` instance later in the line

```
img->data[... = img->data[...
```

(it should presumably be `newImg->data` you are assigning to)

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to fix somethings, but now the resulting image is a black rectangle, not a rotated image. Do you know what could be causing that?

Comment: @DavidRC I've updated my answer with a note of another bug in your code.  The rotation loop was updating the contents of `img` rather than writing to `newImg`

Comment: Sorry, when you spend hours on fiddling with the same piece of code, you lose track of which version you post. Strangely, now I'm getting random noise as the image. I'm going to revise the algorithm I used (I was trying to stay away from arrays).

Answer (score 2):

newImg->data = (PGMPixel*)malloc(newImg->x * newImg->y * sizeof(PGMPixel));

Here you did not initialize your variables.